# get file like pics and media through controller

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I have the following link on my website - `http://mywebsite/multimedia/pronounciation/265.mp3`
which gets me the file bypassing controllers. But I would like to log request and then return this file. So I created controller which logs request and then reroutes to the file:

```
class Controller_GetSound extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {
        Request::factory('multimedia/pronounciation/265.mp3')
                ->method(Request::POST)
                ->post($this->request->post())
                ->execute();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. How can I return resource file from controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana has a send_file function. That function does a good job on splitting large files and sending correct mime types.

@see http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Response#send_file

Your code should be:

```
class Controller_GetSound extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {

        $this->response->send_file('multimedia/pronounciation/265.mp3',TRUE,array(
            'mime_type' => 'audio/mpeg',
        ))
    }
}
```

You actually don't really need to set the mime_type. Kohana will find the correct mime_type for your.

Comment: Thank you! Have you ever used it?

Comment: Yes, i use it to serve user restricted files. Like checking if a user is allowed to download a file. It also supports download "resumes". And if you check the code of that function you can see that there is much more going on than just the mime type.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to implement something known as [X-Sendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/). I think?

The controller would look something like this:

```
class Controller_GetSound extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {
        $this->response->headers(array(
            'Content-Type' => 'audio/mpeg'
            'X-Sendfile' => 'multimedia/pronounciation/265.mp3',
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! S you are saying I'll probably need to download and install this X-Sendfile mod for Apache? Have you ever used it before?

Comment: No, I haven't ever used it. But I would try it if I had a similar need. The usage does not look hard at all, which is why I made a mental note when I saw it mentioned on the Kohana forums. (Probably over a year ago, which is why I remembered the feature and had to google the name.)